# Casting array item to reference MovieClip in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, casting

I have what I think should be a very simple problem.  I have an array and can access an element of it like this:

```
var test = finalArray[0];
```

// Will be a number between 1 and 7

say this will trace a number.

No there is a movieclip on the root of stage whose name is a letter (always the same, say "R") and whatever the number is.  I'm trying to get this movieclip to gotoAndStop at the frame corresponding to the number that is test.  However this isn't working:

```
"R"+[test as MovieClip.gotoAndStop(test)];
```

What am I doing wrong with regard to casting here?
Many thanks

Comment: Many thanks for reply, i can see that I'm doing the casting incorrectly, but I should have been clearer, the movieclip on stage could be one of 7, so it's name could be "R7" or "R2" etc, so I have to somehow append the value of test to R before I try to gotoAndStop if this makes sense?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

`"R"+test` is the name of your clip, so you have to use `getChildByName`:

```
var myMovieClip:MovieClip = this.getChildByName("R" + test.toString()) as MovieClip;
myMovieClip.gotoAndStop(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

The casting should be done like that:

```
(R as MovieClip).gotoAndStop(test);
```

or possibly:

```
 (this["R"] as MovieClip).gotoAndStop(test);
```

Depending on how "R" is created.

Answer (score 0):

if your movieclip name is somthing like "R3"

```
// as3
stage["R"+test].gotoAndStop(test);
// as2
_root["R"+test].gotoAndStop(test);
```

if your movieclip name is "R"

```
// as3
stage["R"].gotoAndStop(test);
// as2
_root["R"].gotoAndStop(test);
```

but calling stage or root from subviews is not the best way for solving problems. Better use eventlisteners.

Comment: Cool, thank you, yes I know what you mean about using listeners as a solution, thanks for help